# Resources to learn how to develop a schedule/appointment system in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture, icalendar

Not a job/task schedule, but actual appointment system people can use to create recurring events (like a calendar). It should support many recurrence patterns such as 1st Monday of each month, every Tues/Thurs, a specific date, etc.

I've been trying to review [RFC 2445](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt), but I'm finding it difficult to absorb, there's **A LOT** of content in it. I've looked through the [sysschedules table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx) from SQL Server, but it is more along the lines of a job schedule (which I'm sure shares some many similarities, but is still melting my brain at this point).

I'll be attempting to build one using ASP.NET MVC, C#, on SQL Server 2008R2. The table schema, how to query for specified dates, etc... still elude me at this time.

Are there resources out there (website, eBook, printed book, etc...) to help programmers learn how to program a schedule/calendar system (free or paid, I don't mind).

Comment: Which aspect of the schedule/appointment system are you struggling with? That's an awfully big domain.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: it seems from the question is that he is struggling with where to start. Where would you start? The answer to this is probably what  he is struggling with right now.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - Primarily, it's the recurrence "stuff". I don't want to have multiple entries in my DB for one event (they don't need to be editable as individual occurrences). The event should follow a recurrence pattern, with a wide range or possibilities (1st Mon of the month, every 2 weeks on Tues/Thurs, etc...). And then... how do I query for "events" occurring on specific days?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion for the task you about to do.

It important to think how different your system will be from the ones that have been build beforeI would recommend looking at some of the open source application some are do great job.

**Here are some thinks that you may find useful**

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148500/Event-Calendar-for-an-ASP-NET-MVC-Application
- http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/index.html
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14107/Using-DayPilot-2-Outlook-like-calendar-scheduling

Comment: When I was working through the sysschedules table, I put together my own schema based off the Freq_type, intervals, etc... that I thought would fit into my design. Then I got to thinking, how would I find all the "events" happening on this Tuesday? Wouldn't be hard for events that fall on every Tues, but what about relative ones, such as recurring every other week on Tues? How does the event know if it's week 1, or week 2? Repeat for days, months, etc... and my brain starts melting and I stop, play some XBOX for the rest of the night and try again the next day. ;)

Comment: yeah you need a good schema and it should work

Comment: If I don't need to individual occurrences of an "event" editable, would the schema on the sysschedules link I posted work? I have Freq_Type, Interval, RelativeFactor, etc... it seemed to be working well, until I tried to imagine how I would query for events which recur with a relative factor (like once every other week). How do I calculate if it's the "on or off" week for the recurring event?

Comment: I think it would work as a partial table design but I think you want to make more advanced I think you need some relation tables like where dates are related to event ids and week ids